# Exponential distribution of runners

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Neil and Patrick go for runs whose lengths are independent and identically distributed exponential random varaibles with $\mu =35$ minutes.

> 1) What is the probability that the first to finish takes atleast 35 minutes to finish running.

My logic: Note $Pr(min(A,B) \geq z) = Pr(A \geq z) \cdot Pr(B \geq z)$, so since they are identically distributed exponential random variables, it should just be $2 \cdot Pr(A \geq z)$. Where $Pr(A \geq z)$ is calculated by $P = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, where $\lambda = 1/35, x = 35$ so $P \approx .0105$, so the answer is $2*P = .02102$?

> 2) What is the probability that Neil's run takes atleast 35 minutes?

My logic: Should just be P as above? So $.0105$?

I feel like I have done this wrong. Can I have confirmation or tips please, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note $Pr(min(A,B) \geq z) = Pr(A \geq z) \cdot Pr(B \geq z)$, so since they are identically distributed exponential random variables, it should just be $2 \cdot Pr(A \geq z)$.

No.

...*since they are identically distributed <s>exponential</s> random variables* and independent, *it should just be* $\Pr(A \geq z)^2$.

> Where $Pr(A \geq z)$ is calculated by $P = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$

No.

...*where $\Pr(A \geq z)$ is* by definition $p=\displaystyle\int_z^\infty\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}\mathrm dt=\mathrm e^{-\lambda z}$.

> 2) What is the probability that Neil's run takes atleast 35 minutes?
>
> My logic: Should just be P as above?

Yes, if $P$ is the correct $p=\mathrm e^{-\lambda z}$ computed above, that is, $p=1/\mathrm e$.

Comment: Yes, that was a silly mistake on the $2 \cdot Pr(A \geq z)$.

I see now, the pdf of X is given by that integral for all $x \geq 0$, and it yields a negative function that goes to zero minus a negative number... That makes sense. Thank you!